# How to use Bluetooth plugin for sending and receiving data from ionic 4 app and IoT application

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, wifi, azure-iot-hub

I want to develop an app to control IoT devices via Bluetooth, but I don't know which Bluetooth plugin use in ionic 4 application to control IoT devices(send and receive messages)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this ionic plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial
that enables serial communication over Bluetooth. It was written for communicating between Android or iOS and an Arduino (not Android to Android or iOS to iOS).

Comment: I'm glad it helps!, if it was the correct answer, mark as it!